# Use KendoUI AngularJS directive in Angular Component

Tags: angularjs, angular, kendo-ui, angular-hybrid

We have an Hybrid app (AngularJS 1.6 & Angular 5) which uses Kendo UI for AngularJS. Architecture of the AngularJS side of the app is fully based on components. We are slowly moving each AngularJS component to Angular and have one component which is using Kendo UI Validator (https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/angular)

I have attempted using angular/upgrade/static approach, but does not really work

```
@Directive({selector: '[kendo-validator]'})
export class KendoValidator extends UpgradeComponent {

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('kendoValidator', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know if there is any way to use Kendo UI AngularJS components in Angular 5 components. For number of reasons (our of my control) we are not in a position to upgrade to Kendo Angular UI as yet -:(

Comment: Ahhh. Thats going to be tricky. You'll be better off creating something similar on your own in Angular. Or maybe look for alternatives.

Comment: Oh well considering the heavy investment in Kendo and Progress in general, unlikely we could ditch Kendo :(, I am going to Open a support ticket